# Using a RegEx via C# to split by keywords except within quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

What is an appropriate regular expression to use with the .NET method `Regex.Split` if I want to split by the keyword `AND` as shown in this string:

```
A1 = B2 AND A2 = 'M AND M' AND A3 NOT IN ( 'E1' , 'E2' )
```

Here is the result I am after:

```
A1 = B2
A2 = 'M AND M'
A3 NOT IN ( 'E1' , 'E2' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string str = "A1 = B2 AND A2 = 'M AND M' AND A3 NOT IN ( 'E1' , 'E2' )";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<!'\w+)\sAND\s(?!\w+')");
string[] arr = regex.Split(str);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TLXSQK53901)

Breaking it down, we start with our term to split on as ' AND '. Then we use a negative lookbehind to ensure that it is not part of a pattern starting with a ' followed by one or more words. Finally we use a negative lookahead to ensure that it is not followed by a pattern of one or more words ending with a '.